# SQL-based FP-Growth Algorithm

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-mining, fpgrowth

so I have an example of an itemset named **tr_table** like this :

```
+---------+-----------+
| tr_kode | item|
+---------+-----------+
| T1      |         1 |
| T1      |         2 |
| T1      |         2 |
| T1      |         5 |
| T2      |         1 |
| T2      |         3 |
| T2      |         4 |
| T2      |         5 |
| T2      |         6 |
| T3      |         1 |
| T3      |         2 |
| T4      |         4 |
| T4      |         2 |
| T4      |         6 |
| T5      |         6 |
| T5      |         5 |
| T5      |         4 |
| T6      |         3 |
| T6      |         6 |
| T6      |         2 |
| T7      |         2 |
| T7      |         1 |
| T7      |         7 |
+---------+-----------+
```

then I set the minimum support to be 20% and make a frequent item view of the table called **freq_item**. This view contains selected frequent items that have been sorted.

```
+------+-----------+
| item | suppCount |
+------+-----------+
|    2 |         6 |
|    1 |         4 |
|    6 |         4 |
|    4 |         3 |
|    5 |         3 |
|    3 |         2 |
+------+-----------+
```

after that I already get a transaction table that has been selected and sorted, which is called **selected_tr**

```
+------+------+
| tid  | item |
+------+------+
| T1   |    2 |
| T1   |    1 |
| T1   |    5 |
| T2   |    1 |
| T2   |    6 |
| T2   |    4 |
| T2   |    5 |
| T2   |    3 |
| T3   |    2 |
| T3   |    1 |
| T4   |    2 |
| T4   |    6 |
| T4   |    4 |
| T5   |    6 |
| T5   |    4 |
| T5   |    5 |
| T6   |    2 |
| T6   |    6 |
| T6   |    3 |
| T7   |    2 |
| T7   |    1 |
+------+------+
```

what I want to ask is, how do you build the fp-tree from selected_tr, then find the frequent pattern based on the fp-growth algorithm. thanks before.

Comment: I don't think you can. How would you even represent the FPtree in SQl? Plus, the construction is an iterative procedure, something SQL really avoids.

Comment: *"Plus, the construction is an iterative procedure, something SQL really avoids"* @Anony-Mousse uhm MySQL supports [iterative](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html) (stored) procedures for some time now?   Or i am missing your real point here?..

Comment: but in this paper says it's possible, it's just that I'm very difficult to understand how he did it. [Link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.7392&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: @RaymondNijland: MySQL extension? Do you have a ANSI SQL definition of that statement? But go ahead and waste your time trying to do FPgrowth in mySQL. Then benchmark against an implementation outside SQL such as pyfim.

Comment: *"MySQL extension? Do you have a ANSI SQL definition of that statement?"* MySQL SQL dialect is tagged so the ANSI/ISO SQL standards does not really matter  @Anony-Mousse  ... but reseach SQL/PSM in the ANSI/ISO SQL standards if you want to find it ...

Comment: this is the topic that I want to discuss in my undergraduate thesis. I know that fp-growth is easier to do with python, but there are some conditions that don't allow me to use python. other than that I'm not too good at python

Comment: *"this is the topic that I want to discuss in my undergraduate thesis."* i already had a feeling this was homework related .. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: but i agree here regardless of the "discussion" about the iterative procedure, ANSI/ISO SQL standard with @Anony-Mousse that it is a bad idea to implement this in MySQL.. When looking more into the paper and needed algorthm which involves string merging and splitting it seams which is not something you should really do in  MySQL...

Comment: sorry before, but I'm not looking for source code. I'm looking for an explanation of the table that I made with the reference I gave about fp-growth. just like, how did the paper do it after that step. but fine, I'm sorry.

Comment: Really, if you are not an extreme SQL expert (and you are undergrad), don't attempt to do a FPtree with SQL. This is bound to fail. Plus, to make FPgrowth work you'll also need to get the projections working, and I think many master students will fail to understand that part of FPgrowth (and even lecturers, that is why many slide sets don't include this part...)

Comment: Before even trying to do this in SQl, you should 1. first learn how to do FPgrowth from A to Z with pen and paper. 2. Implement it once with a language where you can easily model trees with cross-connected nodes, 3. do some tree base iterative code in SQL. Then reconsider if you really want to continue this horrible idea.

Comment: I have learned how FP growth works. data selection based on minimum support, itemset priority, fp tree development, conditional pattern base, and generated rule selection with minimum confidence. if sql is only able to get to the step of sorting transaction data based on itemset priority, let's say that the next step I move to php. it should work right? I think asking here is the last choice, that's why I did it. btw thx, i will try again.